# Is there a surjection of SL(2,Z) to itself with a nontrivial kernel?

Tags: group-theory

Weird question, but I don't think it's obvious. For example, modding out by $2\mathbb{Z}$ gives a surjection $\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}$ with nontrivial kernel.

Comment: Modding out by $2\mathbb{Z}$ gives a surjection $\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}_2$.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No. A group is called [Hopfian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopfian_group) if every surjection $G \to G$ is an isomorphism, and it's known that any finitely generated residually finite group is Hopfian. This includes $\text{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$ (and $\mathbb{Z}$). The proof can be found [here](http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Finitely_generated_and_residually_finite_implies_Hopfian).

Comment: Is there a similar term for groups such that every _injection_ $\: G\to G\:$ is an isomorphism? $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: @Ricky: yes, co-Hopfian (http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Co-Hopfian_group). This is stated in the Wikipedia article.